# Is there a way to trigger a vuex mutation on every input in a q-popup-edit component of a q-td in a q-table?

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex, quasar-framework

i am working with the q-table in an app with vuex. Adding the popup edit to the table and editing a fields content in the browser, i get these errors and warnings in the console (see below).

The app works as expected, but is throwing those errors, but is throwing these funny error messages. I think it is a necessary learning to not just disable strict mode but to understand what is the right way to do this.

How can i trigger a vuex mutation on user input into this q-popup-edit in  a way that the browser will not throw these error messages?

I have tried suppressing the warning which makes no real sense.

I have read the documentation
https://quasar.dev/vue-components/popup-edit

which holds no references to any callback function for on user input

```
...
<template>
  <div class="q-pa-md">
    <q-table
      title="Bewerber"
      :data="data"
      :columns="columns"
      row-key="id"
      binary-state-sort
      separator="cell"
      selection="single"
      :selected.sync="selected"
    >
    <template v-slot:body="props">
        <q-tr :props="props">
          <q-td auto-width>
            <q-checkbox dense v-model="props.selected" />
          </q-td>
          <q-td key="id" :props="props">
            {{ props.row.id }}
          </q-td>
          <q-td key="added" :props="props">
            {{ props.row.added }}
            <q-popup-edit v-model="props.row.added" buttons @save="saveRow(props.row)">
              <q-input type="text"  v-model="props.row.added" dense autofocus counter />
            </q-popup-edit>
          </q-td>

...



vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "function () { return this._data.$$state }": "Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers."

(found in <Root>)
warn @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619
logError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1884
globalHandleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1879
handleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1839
run @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4564
update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4536
notify @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:730
reactiveSetter @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1055
set @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1077
callback @ list.vue?994d:645
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854
invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2179
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854
Vue.$emit @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3882
emitValueFn @ QInput.js?27f9:145
emitValue @ QInput.js?27f9:162
onInput @ QInput.js?27f9:126
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854
invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2179
original._wrapper @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6911
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.
    at assert (vuex.esm.js?2f62:90)
    at Vue.store._vm.$watch.deep (vuex.esm.js?2f62:774)
    at Watcher.run (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4562)
    at Watcher.update (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4536)
    at Dep.notify (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:730)
    at Object.reactiveSetter [as address_line_1] (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1055)
    at Proxy.set (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1077)
    at callback (list.vue?994d:645)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854)
    at VueComponent.invoker (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2179)
```

**EDIT: (after Guillaume Meral's comment below, thx for pointing out this missing info)**

The data prop is set like this:

```
computed: {
    data: function () {
      return this.$store.getters['candidate/getCandidates']
    }
  },
```

I expect to be able to catch these input events and call a vuex action to mutate the state properly and thereby get rid of the errors / warnings. But there seems to be little documentation about this, maybe i am overseeing something?

This is my first question on Stackoverflow. Please let me know if i need to update my question or specify anything in more detail.

Thanks for your help @community.

**EDIT: ** my first attempted solution was to add setters to the computed property like described in the link posted by Guillaume Meral below.

I have implemented this change, looking like this:

```
  computed: {
    data: {
      // getter
      get: function () {
        return this.$store.getters['candidate/getCandidates']
      },
      // setter
      set: function (newData) {
        this.$store.dispatch('candidate/updateCandidateList', newData)
      }
    }
  },
```

with an action

```
export function updateCandidateList (state, data) {
  state.commit('setCandidates', data)
}
```

and a mutation

```
export function setCandidates (state, data) {
  if (data) {
    state.candidates = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
  } else {
    state.candidates = null
  }
}
```

and state

```
export default {
  candidates: []
}
```

**Still the warnings persist in the console**

```
[Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "function () { return this._data.$$state }": "Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers."(found in <Root>)

vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.
    at assert (vuex.esm.js?2f62:90)
    at Vue.store._vm.$watch.deep (vuex.esm.js?2f62:774)
    at Watcher.run (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4562)
    at Watcher.update (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4536)
    at Dep.notify (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:730)
    at Object.reactiveSetter [as added] (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1055)
    at Proxy.set (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1077)
    at callback (list.vue?994d:93)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1854)
    at VueComponent.invoker (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2179)
```

sidenote: also adding  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)) anywhere wont help ^^

I don't get what is wrong here. Let me know if you do, please.

**SOLUTION**

Mapstate solved the problem for me. It does suppress the errors on every keystroke done in the text input field before hitting the save button.

```
  computed: {
    ...mapState('candidate', {
      data: state => state.candidate
    })
  },
```

Comment: Without seeing the way props.row.added it is not possible to give a definitive answer. However i suspect that it is directly assigned with a part of the state of the store. What you need to do is using a computed property with a getter and a setter part like here : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter  
In the getter you get the value from the store, in the setter, you commit a mutation or dispatch an action.

Comment: The data prop is added like this:

`computed: {
    data: function () {
      return this.$store.getters['candidate/getCandidates']
    }
  }`

So basically i have to add getter and setter to this to make it work (it is only the getter now implicitly)?

Comment: I have implemented the proposed changes, but the error message persists. I have updated the question with some more details.

Comment: Next step for you would be to cut down the interactions with vuex to see where the problem comes from precisely. You could try to replace the data by a static array like in the quasar doc to see if you still have an error. (By the way i really don't like the name `data`, it is confusing because vue components also have a data property.

Comment: I will give it a try and provide the result here in the next few days

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

Mapstate solved the problem for me. It does suppress the errors on every keystroke done in the text input field before hitting the save button.

```
  computed: {
    ...mapState('candidate', {
      data: state => state.candidate
    })
  },
```